# Mostrar dato de tipo Date en TableView JavaFX

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

Tengo una consulta SQL que trae dos(2) datos que son nombre y  licenciaexpira

```
SELECT nombre, licenciaexpira FROM conductores
```

He logrado mostrar el nombre en mi Tabla pero la fecha no.
estube investigando y me di cuenta que mi dato licenciaexpira en mysql es de Tipo "Date" pero no logro entender como mostrarlo ya que cambio el tipo de dato en el codigo pero me muestra Error.

aqui el codigo:

```
public class Panel2{
    private StringProperty Nombre;
    private StringProperty FechaVence;

    public Panel2(String Nombre, String FechaVence) { 
        this.Nombre = new SimpleStringProperty(Nombre);
        this.FechaVence = new SimpleStringProperty(FechaVence);
    }

    //Metodos atributo: Nombre
    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre.get();
    }
    public void setNombre(String Nombre) {
        this.Nombre = new SimpleStringProperty(Nombre);
    }
    public StringProperty NombreProperty() {
        return Nombre;
    }
    //Metodos atributo: FechaVence
    public String getFechaVence() {
        return FechaVence.get();
    }
    public void setFechaVence(String FechaVence) {
        this.FechaVence = new SimpleStringProperty(FechaVence);
    }
    public StringProperty FechaVenceProperty() {
        return FechaVence;
    }
        //
    public static void mostrarFechaLicenciasVence(Connection connection, ObservableList<Panel2> infofechasvence) {
        try {
            Statement instruccion = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultado = instruccion.executeQuery("SELECT nombre, licenciaexpira FROM conductores");
            while (resultado.next()) {
                infofechasvence.add(
                        new Panel2(
                                resultado.getString("nombre"),
                                resultado.getString("licenciaexpira")
                        )
                );
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Aqui el Controller:

```
 infofechasvence = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    Panel2.mostrarFechaLicenciasVence(conexion.getConnection(), infofechasvence);
    tbl_fechasexpiralic.setItems(infofechasvence);

    clmnnombre.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Panel2, String>("nombre")
    );
    clmnfechaexpira.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Panel2, String>("licenciaexpira")
    );
```

La tabla se muestra de esta manera:

[image: tab]

Comment: Toma en cuenta que tu `CATCH` vacío (mala práctica) va a ignorar cualquier error que ocurra. Tal vez tienes algún error, pero ni te das cuenta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema realmente no esta en el tipo de dato Fecha, creo que esta en el "Factory" que le estas estableciendo a las columnas.

Tu lo tienes asi:

```
 clmnnombre.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Panel2, String>("nombre")
);
clmnfechaexpira.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Panel2, String>("licenciaexpira")
);
```

Intenta ponerlo asi:

```
 clmnnombre.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Panel2, String>("Nombre")
);
clmnfechaexpira.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Panel2, String>("FechaVence")
);
```

Verifica y comenta si te ha funcionado.

Comment: Correcto Funcionando aunque tendre que investigar mas sobre estos Factory Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba cambiando el tipo de datos de String a Date en el panel2 de esta manera:

```
public Panel2(String Nombre, Date FechaVence) { 
    this.Nombre = new SimpleStringProperty(Nombre);
    this.FechaVence = new SimpleStringProperty(FechaVence);
}
```

Luego usa el método getDate() para obtener la fecha desde la base da datos:

```
resultado.getDate("licenciaexpira");
```